# Install libsecret inside Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, sudo

I'm trying to install the git credential helper with Libsecret in my Docker container on my company's remote machine (to which I've ssh-ed).

I'm a beginner with Docker and tried to just use the method [online](https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/git-credential-storage-libsecret)

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
cd /home/<my_username>/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /home/<my_username>/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

The only thing I've changed (privacy reasons) is my actual username to `<my_username>`. Here I get the problem `sudo: unable to resolve host` and then more problems later in spite of install progressing.

Anyone able to help?

Full debug below:

```
# sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
sudo: unable to resolve host 1fee2c616ef4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-secret-1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev
  libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libsecret-common pkg-config python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
Suggested packages:
  libglib2.0-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-secret-1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3
  libpcrecpp0v5 libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev libsecret-common pkg-config python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglib2.0-0
1 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Need to get 4327 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 [1172 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgirepository-1.0-1 amd64 1.56.1-1 [82.0 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gir1.2-glib-2.0 amd64 1.56.1-1 [131 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsecret-common all 0.18.6-1 [4452 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsecret-1-0 amd64 0.18.6-1 [94.6 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gir1.2-secret-1 amd64 0.18.6-1 [7440 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 [68.8 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-lib2to3 all 3.6.9-1~18.04 [77.4 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-distutils all 3.6.9-1~18.04 [144 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev-bin amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 [102 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcre16-3 amd64 2:8.39-9 [147 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcre32-3 amd64 2:8.39-9 [138 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcrecpp0v5 amd64 2:8.39-9 [15.3 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcre3-dev amd64 2:8.39-9 [537 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 pkg-config amd64 0.29.1-0ubuntu2 [45.0 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 [1386 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsecret-1-dev amd64 0.18.6-1 [176 kB]
Fetched 4327 kB in 0s (31.7 MB/s)          
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 20991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libglib2.0-0_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) over (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libgirepository-1.0-1_1.56.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.56.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-gir1.2-glib-2.0_1.56.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 (1.56.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsecret-common.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libsecret-common_0.18.6-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsecret-common (0.18.6-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsecret-1-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libsecret-1-0_0.18.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsecret-1-0:amd64 (0.18.6-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-secret-1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-gir1.2-secret-1_0.18.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-secret-1:amd64 (0.18.6-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglib2.0-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-lib2to3.
Preparing to unpack .../07-python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-distutils.
Preparing to unpack .../08-python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglib2.0-dev-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libglib2.0-dev-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-dev-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre16-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libpcre16-3_2%3a8.39-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre16-3:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre32-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libpcre32-3_2%3a8.39-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre32-3:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcrecpp0v5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libpcrecpp0v5_2%3a8.39-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcrecpp0v5:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre3-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libpcre3-dev_2%3a8.39-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre3-dev:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pkg-config.
Preparing to unpack .../14-pkg-config_0.29.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pkg-config (0.29.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglib2.0-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libglib2.0-dev_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsecret-1-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libsecret-1-dev_0.18.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsecret-1-dev:amd64 (0.18.6-1) ...
Setting up libsecret-common (0.18.6-1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
No schema files found: doing nothing.
Setting up libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.56.1-1) ...
Setting up pkg-config (0.29.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 (1.56.1-1) ...
Setting up libpcrecpp0v5:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Setting up libpcre32-3:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Setting up libpcre16-3:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
Setting up libsecret-1-0:amd64 (0.18.6-1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
Setting up python3-distutils (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
Setting up libpcre3-dev:amd64 (2:8.39-9) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-dev-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...
Setting up gir1.2-secret-1:amd64 (0.18.6-1) ...
Setting up libsecret-1-dev:amd64 (0.18.6-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
# cd /home/<my_username>/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
/bin/sh: 7: cd: can't cd to /home/<my_username>/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
# cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
# sudo make
sudo: unable to resolve host 1fee2c616ef4

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: `No targets specified and no makefile found` is your problem.

Comment: Why bother with `# sudo make`? You appear to be the root user so just run `make`

Comment: This looks like there is no such `/home/<my_username>/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/` directory. Why do you expect anything to be there? Maybe download something there first? Or create the directory?

Comment: @KamilCuk as you said, ```No targets specified and no makefile found``` remains as a problem even if I first ```mkdir /home/<my_username>/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/``` and then try to ```make``` or ```sudo make``` inside it

Comment: Because there is no Makefile there.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your Dockerfile?  Anything you install in an interactive shell in a container will be lost as soon as the container exits.  (For a couple of practical reasons, consider not running `git` in Docker at all; instead, add your Dockerfile and similar artifacts to source control, and check out the repository on the host before building the image.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect a Makefile to be there. The ubuntu package maintainers in their wisdom decided to ship the Makefile for libsecret with git rather than with libsecret, so you will have to do the install step for git first and make sure it gets installed to /home/
You'll also want to avoid using sudo on any builds going to your user directory else you'll likely end up with permission issues later due to everything being root owned.