# gnome-keyring and libsecret for Git credentials on a headless Ubuntu in a Docker container

Tags: git, docker, gnome-keyring-daemon

**TL;DR**

We are using the [Git extension for JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git). We want to use `gnome-keyring` to cache our GitHub credentials. Following the [documentation](https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/git-credential-storage-libsecret) (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385690/how-to-use-git-with-gnome-keyring-integration) and [this](https://gist.github.com/maelvls/79d49740ce9208c26d6a1b10b0d95b5e)), we run

```sh
apt update && apt install -y \
build-essential \
gnome-keyring \
libglib2.0-dev \
libsecret-1-0 \
libsecret-1-dev
```

but `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` is empty, so `make` has nothing to do. We don't seem to be the only ones with this issue: see [this](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/5416#issuecomment-1024374542) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591940/install-libsecret-inside-docker-container). **Why is the directory not being populated?**

---

**Details**

Here is our (stripped down) Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:hub-4.0.2

USER 1000
COPY start_up.sh /tmp/

USER root
RUN chmod +x /tmp/start_up.sh
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
  build-essential \
  gnome-keyring \
  libglib2.0-dev \
  libsecret-1-0 \
  libsecret-1-dev

USER 1000

# other stuff
```

`start_script.sh` looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l

dbus-run-session -- sh -c 'echo "foo" | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock && exec jupyterhub-singleuser "$@"'
```

(We don't actually use `foo`, but rather an external secret via an environment variable. That's not relevant here though?) This script is run by k8s when a container is deployed; here is the relevant part of the `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
singleuser:
  cmd: /tmp/start_up.sh
  nodeSelector: 
     "lifecycle" : "jupyterhub"
```

The idea is to start the jupyterhub-singleuser in a D-Bus shell so that the keyring backend works: see [this](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring#using-keyring-on-headless-linux-systems-in-a-docker-container) and [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-server-source-script-on-launch/15372/).

Comment: In Debian the directory comes from package `git`: `dpkg-query -S /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` outputs `git: /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` and `dpkg-query -L git | grep -F /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` lists 2 files: `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/Makefile
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret.c`. But in Ubuntu the directory is empty even if the package `git` contains the directory. I'm puzzled!

Comment: Do you just need a credential helper that reads a value from the environment or from some other location?  As you've found, trying to run a libsecret backend (like gnome-keyring) is generally not easy to do in a headless environment.

Comment: @bk2204 We want a secure way to cache each user's Git credentials after they have entered them that is compatible with the jupyterlab-git extension. It does not have to be with libsecret/gnome-keyring. We've been using SSH so far, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with jupyterlab-git and there are issues around access to the SSH keys when users collaborate using the jupyter-collaboration-extension. We're already using gnome-keyring for other connections. As you say, it wasn't the easiest to set up, but it does work.

Comment: Ok got (it was explained to me): it's screwed Ubuntu called "minimized". See https://askubuntu.com/q/1173337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [explained to me](https://phd-ru.dreamwidth.org/383962.html?thread=257498#cmt257498): Ubuntu containers are "minimized". See https://askubuntu.com/q/1173337

Default Ubuntu containers can be easily unminimized but I have problems running `unminimize` in *jupyter/minimal-notebook:hub-4.0.2* — 1st, it unminimizes too much and 2nd, it fails after some time. So I decided to use 2 containers — start with unminimized Ubuntu, install `git`, and then copy `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/` to *jupyter/minimal-notebook:hub-4.0.2*. This works for me:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS ubuntu-22.04

# See https://askubuntu.com/q/1173337
RUN yes | unminimize

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git


FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:hub-4.0.2

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  git \
  gnome-keyring \
  libglib2.0-dev \
  libsecret-1-0 \
  libsecret-1-dev

COPY --from=ubuntu-22.04 \
  /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret \
  /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
```